# Hi is there a way to code the minimum value that I want to get?

Tags: r

my data is as follows:

```
Year        Type         Amount
2013         A            100
2013         B            150
2013         C            100
2013         D            300
2014         A            200
2014         B            150
2014         C            170
2014         D            100
2014         E            120
2015         A            100
2015         B            350
2015         C            670
2015         D            300
2015         E            220
```

I'd like to only extract such that it gets the earliest and latest year of each type (A,B,C,D,E)
As seen, the earliest year of E starts from 2014, instead of 2013.

The output that I want will look like this:

```
Year        Type         Amount
2013         A            100
2013         B            150
2013         C            100
2013         D            300
2014         E            120
2015         A            100
2015         B            350
2015         C            670
2015         D            300
2015         E            220
```

Is there any way to code this, without hardcoding? This is in a dataframe format

Comment: Try: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(Type) %>% filter(Year == min(Year) | Year == max(Year))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can group by `Type` and select Year with the condition that it is the minimum or maximum `Year` for each `Type`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  filter(Year == min(Year) | Year == max(Year))
```

Gives us:

```
 Year Type  Amount
   <int> <chr>  <int>
 1  2013 A        100
 2  2013 B        150
 3  2013 C        100
 4  2013 D        300
 5  2014 E        120
 6  2015 A        100
 7  2015 B        350
 8  2015 C        670
 9  2015 D        300
10  2015 E        220
```

For your follow up, to calculate percent increase:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  filter(Year == min(Year) | Year == max(Year)) %>% 
  arrange(Type) %>% 
  mutate(pct_change = (Amount[Year == max(Year)]/Amount[Year == min(Year)] - 1)*100)
```

Gives us:

```
 Year Type  Amount pct_change
   <int> <chr>  <int>      <dbl>
 1  2013 A        100        0  
 2  2015 A        100        0  
 3  2013 B        150      133. 
 4  2015 B        350      133. 
 5  2013 C        100      570  
 6  2015 C        670      570  
 7  2013 D        300        0  
 8  2015 D        300        0  
 9  2014 E        120       83.3
10  2015 E        220       83.3
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to code the percentage change in the amount? I'd like to create a new dataframe that shows the percentage change in the amount of all types (A to E) between the 2 years that each type have in this df.

Comment: Is there a way for me to create the percentage change into a new dataframe? Is it possible to do so with distinct(pct_change)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ave` testing for each *Type* if *Year* is either `min` or `max`:

```
x[ave(x$Year, x$Type, FUN=function(y) y==min(y) | y==max(y))==1,]
#   Year Type Amount
#1  2013    A    100
#2  2013    B    150
#3  2013    C    100
#4  2013    D    300
#9  2014    E    120
#10 2015    A    100
#11 2015    B    350
#12 2015    C    670
#13 2015    D    300
#14 2015    E    220
```

or using `range` and `%in%`

```
x[ave(x$Year, x$Type, FUN=function(y) y %in% range(y))==1,]
```